# Is $f(z)=z\sin(1/z)$ continuous for $z\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

I have $$f(z)=z*\sin(1/z)$$ for $z\neq 0$ and $$f(0)=0$$ to see whether the function is continuous or discontinuous at 0,  $z\rightarrow 0$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$. My first idea was to express the function as series but didn´t get far. Then I tried to transform the function so I could get a nice form but since the sine function is not bounded for the complex numbers I couldn´t get the limit. Is there any way to show it or prove it?

Comment: your function is undefined at $z = 0$. You have to define it first.

Comment: I forgot to write it. $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Peter It's not about differentiability.
VariableXYZ You just have to prove that $$\lim_{z\to 0} z \sin \frac{1}{z} = 0 $$
If this is true, then the function is continuous. But it is not the case (see the answer below).

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: @Azlif I´m well aware of that, but the problem is, I can´t prove it or at least I don´t know-how. I always encounter some problem or undefined result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $x > 0$ : 
$$f(-ix) = -ix\sin(\frac{1}{-ix}) = -ix \sin(i\frac{1}{x})= x\sinh(\frac{1}{x}) \longrightarrow +\infty$$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $f$ is not continuous at 0.

Comment: But since x approaches 0 and $sinh(1/x)$ approaches infinity, how can we be sure the function approaches infinity? Is it because sinh approaches infinity faster than x 0 or?

Comment: and of course thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot because the function is at the end real I can apply L´Hopital rule and solve it... Thank you

Comment: you're more than welcome